# show that $f(x, y) = (\cos(y), \frac{x^2}{3})$ is a contraction and has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be $f(x, y) = (\cos(y), \frac{x^2}{3})$. Show that $f$ is a contraction, that there exists a fixed point of $f$, and use at least 4 iterations of Newton's method to approximate the fixed point.

I am not sure where to begin on this. I know the necessary conditions for a contraction, but I do not know how to derive it for this $f$F. I also do not know how to approximate the fixed point via Newton's method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

$$\| f(b) - f(a) \| \leq \sup (\lvert \| df(c) \| \lvert) \cdot \| b-a \|$$

for $c \in [a,b] = \{\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b, \lambda \in [0,1] \}$. Of course in this case

$$df(c)=df(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $f=(f_{1},f_{2})$ and $df(x,y)\cdot(h,k)^{T} = (-k \sin(y),\frac{2}{3}xh)^{T}$ and so

\begin{align}
\| df(x,y)\cdot(h,k)^{T} \|_{1} &= \big\lvert k \sin(y) \big\lvert + \frac{2}{3} \big\lvert xh \big\lvert \\
&\leq \sin(1)(\lvert k\lvert+\lvert h\lvert) \\\\
\implies \| df(x,y) \cdot (h,k)^{T} \|_{1} &\leq \sin(1) \| (h,k) \|_{1}
\end{align}

thus $\lvert \| df(c) \| \lvert \le \sin(1) < 1$ we can conclude that $f$ is a contraction.